# Using Apache web server for downloading a file

Tags: apache-2.2, centos6

On a Centos-6 machine, I setup Apache web server and the default folder is `/var/www/html`. In the presence of an empty `index.html`, by entering the machine's IP address into the browser, I see the blank white screen. That mean, the web server is working.

As I put a file for download, the problem is when I enter the IP address of the machine, I still see the blank while page. I  expect to see a tree like structure like [this](https://fedorapeople.org/groups/virt/virtio-win/repo/stable/).

How can I fix it?

Comment: [mod_autoindex](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_autoindex.html)

Comment: I saw that, but which one is needed for my problem? It is very lengthy and comprehensive

Comment: That is why the page comes with a Summary ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to remove the `index.html` file (or rename it to something that don't end with `.html` or `.php`). You could also create a new sub directory in `/var/www/html`, called `download` (just for an example), and then browse to it with `http://ip-address/download/`.

Comment: With the solution you gave, I see the default's Apache test page!!

Comment: I updated my answer, try creating a sub directory instead.

Comment: That only works when the `Options` directive already inlcudes  `+Indexes` .